# What happens when a contracted object going at speeds comparable to light is fit in a tight space, but has been brought to rest

Tags: special-relativity

What happens when a rod of length L moving at a speed comparable to the speed of light, is made to fit in a space of length say 3/4*L and is brought to rest.
Does it exert some force on the walls surrounding it? If so, how much?

And another related question:
How does the observer moving with the rod explain it(or see it)? Because if say the rod(of length L) according to another observer fits in a space of length L/2 due to its velocity, then the person moving with the rod is somehow supposed to see the rod of Length L fit into (L/2)/2 or L/4 of space.

Comment: Give this a thought; wouldn't the container have to move too?

Comment: @HritikNarayan are you referring to the relative motion? As in the argument that the container can also be though of to be moving in the opposite direction with the same velocity?

Comment: No, the container should be moving with the same speed as the rod if the rod is contained in it. The same length contraction affects the container too.

Comment: Google for "barn and pole paradox".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the question [A Special Relativity Paradox: The Barn and the Pole](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/barn_pole.html) in the Usenet Physics FAQ.

Quoting part of the answer here.  (The exact numbers differ a bit from your question, but that doesn't change the significant part of the question.)

> These are the props.  You own a barn, 40m long, with automatic doors at either end, that can be opened and closed simultaneously by a switch.  You also have a pole, 80m long, which of course won't fit in the barn.
>
> Now someone takes the pole and tries to run (at nearly the speed of light) through the barn with the pole horizontal.  Special Relativity (SR) says that a moving object is contracted in the direction of motion: this is called the Lorentz Contraction.  So, if the pole is set in motion lengthwise, then it will contract in the reference frame of a stationary observer.
>
> You are that observer, sitting on the barn roof.  You see the pole coming towards you, and it has contracted to a bit less than 40m, in your reference frame.
>
> So, as the pole passes through the barn, there is an instant when it is completely within the barn.  At that instant, you close both doors simultaneously, with your switch.  Of course, you open them again pretty quickly, but at least momentarily you had the contracted pole shut up in your barn.  The runner emerges from the far door unscathed.
>
> But consider the problem from the point of view of the runner.  She will regard the pole as stationary, and the barn as approaching at high speed.  In this reference frame, the pole is still 80m long, and the barn is less than 20 meters long.  Surely the runner is in trouble if the doors close while she is inside.  The pole is sure to get caught.
>
> Well does the pole get caught in the door or doesn't it?  You can't have it both ways.  This is the "Barn-pole paradox." The answer is buried in the misuse of the word "simultaneously" back in the first sentence of the story.  In SR, that events separated in space that appear simultaneous in one frame of reference need not appear simultaneous in another frame of reference.  The closing doors are two such separate events.
>
> SR explains that the two doors are never closed at the same time in the runner's frame of reference.  So there is always room for the pole.  In fact, the Lorentz transformation for time is
>
> $$ t' = (t-v\cdot x/c^2)/sqrt(1-v^2/c^2) $$
>
> It's the $v\cdot x$ term in the numerator that causes the mischief here.  In the runner's frame the more distant event (larger $x$) happens earlier.  The far door is closed first.  It opens before she gets there, and the near door closes behind her.  Safe again — either way you look at it, provided you remember that simultaneity is not a constant of physics.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it perfectly answers the second half of the question, but not the first one.
In the above analogy, What if we do not open the door after the pole fits in? Does the pole, now at rest, exert some force? If so, how much?

Comment: The original question I link to also answers what happens if you keep the doors closed.  However, the answer may depend on what precisely you mean by "brought to rest" in the question.